# Read/write file contents into/out of ArrayList<Byte>

Tags: java, file, arraylist

I need to read a very large file (1.11gb) into memory and process it in bytes. The only way for me to do this is to use an ArrayList (I can't use a byte[] because then it will exceed the limit).
There is no way to make the file smaller (I'm using it as a test to test how long my program processes data).
I then need to drop an ArrayList back onto the hard drive as a file (still 1.11gb)
I'm not as worried about writing as I am reading.
Also speed is of the essence so sub segmenting is to be avoided unless anyone out there has a quick way of doing so.

Comment: Please explain: _I can't use a byte[] because then it will exceed the limit_

Comment: `ArrayList<Byte>` is a `byte[]` under the hood

Comment: @kaykay No it's not, it's an Object[]. Which uses 4 or 8 times as much memory as the byte array would.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis arrays have a max length of 2^31-1 places, that is too little for my program (it's a file manipulation program)

Comment: @stealth9799 ArrayLists have the same limit, since they use arrays. still 2^31 is roughly 2gb which is big enough to hold a 1.1gb file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an [X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You do not explain why you want to do what you want to do, which would probably lead to a more appropriate solution. In every scenario I can think of this is about the most naive and worst way to process a file at the `byte` level.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to solve this problem the wrong way (and it won't work<sup>1</sup>).

The possible ways to solve this are:

- Redesign the algorithm so that it doesn't *need* to read the entire file into memory ... in one go.
- Read the data into multiple `byte[]` objects to get around the `2^31` array size limit.
- Map the file using multiple `ByteBuffer` objects<sup>2</sup>; see [Java MemoryMapping big files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675748/java-memorymapping-big-files).

---

<sup>1 - It won't work because `ArrayList` has an `Object[]` inside, and is therefore subject to the same limitation you have with byte arrays.  In addition, an `ArrayList<Byte>` will take 4 to 8 times as much memory as a `byte[]` representing the same number of bytes.  Or more, if you populate the `ArrayList<Byte>` with `Byte` objects instantiated the wrong way.</sup>

<sup>2 - The `Buffer` APIs all use `int` sizes and offsets, and (AFAIK) do not support mapping of files >= 2^31 bytes into a single `Buffer`.</sup>