# Fast memory manipulation in Java?

Tags: java, math, io, buffer, signal-processing

I am a bit of a newbie to Java (prior experience with C on embedded platforms), so please forgive me if this question is very trivial.

I need to implement some signal processing algorithms in Java. I know Java is probably not the best language to do this [1], but the Java requirement has come in primarily because the rest of my team is not comfortable with C at all.

What we need to do at a high level is to read some files containing video frames, process them (gather some statistics about them) and then write them back to disk. The processing will involve reading in a few kB of data and parsing them somehow, possibly with some kind of transforms. i.e. I expect we will need to do a *lot* of byte-addressed random memory accesses. And I'll need to do about 30 frames per second and a few tens of thousands of such operations every frame (so possibly 100s of 1000s of ops per second)

I do not know the 'internals' of Java very well, but from what I read I believe the memory that Java sees is far abstracted from the actual virtual memory that the OS itself provides [2].

What buffer management libraries should I use so that I can get the best possible performance? I've seen a few (NIO [3], Java 2d [4], etc) but I am not able to find which is faster, or if there are any other options that I am missing. Do you guys have any suggestions or pointers [5] for me?

I will also be doing lots of arithmetic, so are there any libraries that do 'faster' arithmetic? I come from a world where I could accelerate almost everything on the hardware but now I need to run this on a PC so I am not sure if there are any such options available.

Any other suggestions or help you guys could provide will be much appreciated!

- [1] [Signal processing library in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636686/signal-processing-library-in-java)
- [2] Is this understanding correct at all? Is there anywhere I can find out how "Java memory" maps to lower level memory?
- [3] http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html
- [4] http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/2D/index.jsp
- [5] No pun intended.

Comment: The thing is, most signal processing in Java will look almost identical to C, because it will almost inevitably be implemented in a procedural style.  I don't know why your coworkers would be so scared of this.  Take away objects and Java starts to look a lot like C.

Comment: [2] This is correct. The JVM maintains its own memory and has some quite high performance garbage collection algorithms. It also does a lot of dynamic optimisation, so I would recommend writing up your algorithm and profiling it to evaluate your performance bottlenecks.

Comment: @MarkPeters yes, that is true - I guess it's more inertia than anything else.

Comment: I found a link that explains some bits of NIO in greater detail - I thought it might help : http://www.cs.brown.edu/courses/cs161/papers/j-nio-ltr.pdf

Comment: To be completely fair, if your group, as a whole, is not comfortable with the C programming language, then what business does the group have implementing signal processing algorithms? It would be worth it for the group to learn C while developing this project.

Answer (score 0):

I hope following link might helpful to you

- [Buffered RandomAccessFile java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614206/buffered-randomaccessfile-java)
- [Binary search in a sorted (memory-mapped ?) file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736556/binary-search-in-a-sorted-memory-mapped-file-in-java)
- [Mapped buffers (file mapping)](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/io/nio_mapped_buffer.shtml)

Comment: OK, most of these links seem to indicate that the MappedByteBuffer from NIO is the way to go, so I guess I'll give that a try.