# How to improve RandomAccessFile usage?

Tags: java, android

I'm using a `RandomAccessFile` to **rw** data to it constantly. The size of the file can range from 5MB up to 200MB. This file is used as a **circular buffer**.

My main concern is the constant seek before a read and write.

What happens after seek? Does part of the file data get buffered right away into memory? Does it even do anything after a seek?

I want to understand how it works and how I could improve the performance of using the `RandomAccessFile` to read write at different positions.  I just feel the constant seek is possibly using too many resources?

**Possible solution to avoid constant seek?**

1. Instantiate two `RandomAccessFile` instances one to read and the other to write. Of course these would be tightly synchronized.
2. Use two `FileChannels`. Not even sure how I could prevent the pointer from moving when I need to read the tail of my buffer or the head of the buffer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614206/buffered-randomaccessfile-java might help

Comment: Thanks for the link... Let me update my question with a bit more stuff I'm figuring out thanks to that post...